# Commands for searching sensitive files in linux

Tags: linux, windows, shell

Does anybody has an idea how to use these search commands for finding sensitive files in a linux shell. The one I have are for windows. Note that I have to specify the extension as well. Thank you in advance :)

```
1. findstr /si password *.txt OR findstr /si password *.txt *.ini *.config *.xml

2. dir /s *pass* == *cred* == *vnc* == *.config*
```

Comment: Are you searching just for the files or specific strings inside the files ?

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for reaching out. The first one searches for the word password in the specified files (with these extensions). And the second, looks for files and folder containing (in their name) the words *pass*, *cred* for e.g. log.config, credential-manager.exe, etc.

Comment: `grep` and `find`